# Why is my list-style-image being positioned differently in different browsers

Tags: html, css, html-lists, css-float

On this page:

- http://run.xxmn.com/new/hot

in Chrome and IE 7, the bullet image I’ve applied to the “Top Coupons” list with `list-style-image` is on the right hand side of each list item.

In Firefox, it’s on the left, which is what I want.

How can I make it be on the left in Chrome and IE 7 too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest trying

> li { padding-left: 20px; background: url(YOURIMAGE) no-repeat 0 50%; }

Comment: thanks for your answer. you're right. if i use background, it will be displayed in all kinds of brower. but is there a way not using background to get that. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think Chrome and IE 7 might be seeing the (Japanese? Chinese?) text on the page, and automatically switching to right-to-left rendering, which would put list bullets on the right of their list items.

I think [lushnis’s solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212891/why-is-my-list-style-image-being-positioned-differently-in-different-browsers/4213020#4213020) is the best. You could amend the page or the list items to run left-to-right in CSS, but I’m not sure if this would screw up the text rendering.